# documents with tags in mongodb: getting tag counts

Tags: mongodb, count, tags

I have a `collection1` of documents with tags in MongoDB. The tags are an embedded array of strings:

```
{
    name: 'someObj',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', ...]
}
```

I want to know the count of each tag in the collection. Therefore I have another `collection2` with tag counts:

```
{
    { 
        tag: 'tag1',
        score: 2
    }
    { 
        tag: 'tag2',
        score: 10
    }
}
```

Now I have to keep both in sync. It is rather trivial when inserting to or removing from `collection1`. However when I update `collection1` I do the following:

1.) get the old document

```
var oldObj = collection1.find({ _id: id });
```

2.) calculate the difference between old and new tag arrays

```
var removedTags = $(oldObj.tags).not(obj.tags).get();
var insertedTags = $(obj.tags).not(oldObj.tags).get();
```

3.) update the old document

```
collection1.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: obj }
);
```

4.) update the scores of inserted & removed tags

```
// increment score of each inserted tag
insertedTags.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    // $inc will set score = 1 on insert
    collection2.update(
        { tag: val },
        { $inc: { score: 1 } },
        { upsert: true }
    )
});
// decrement score of each removed tag
removedTags.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    // $inc will set score = -1 on insert
    collection2.update(
        { tag: val },
        { $inc: { score: -1 } },
        { upsert: true }
    )
});
```

My questions:

A) Is this approach of keeping book of scores separately efficient? Or is there a more efficient one-time query to get the scores from collection1?

B) Even if keeping book separately is the better choice: can that be done in less steps, e.g. letting mongoDB calculate what tags are new / removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, as nickmilion correctly states, would be an aggregation. Though I would do it with a nack: we'll save its results in a collection. What will do is to trade real time results for an extreme speed boost.

#### How I would do it

More often than not, the need for real time results is overestimated. Hence, I'd go with precalculated stats for the tags and renew it every 5 minutes or so. That should be well enough, since most of such calls are requested async by the client and hence some delay in case the calculation has to be made on a specific request is negligible.

```js
db.tags.aggregate(
  {$unwind:"$tags"},
  {$group: { _id:"$tags", score:{"$sum":1} } },
  {$out:"tagStats"}
)
db.tagStats.update(
  {'lastRun':{$exists:true}},
  {'lastRun':new Date()},
  {upsert:true}
)

db.tagStats.ensureIndex({lastRun:1}, {sparse:true})
```

Ok, here is the deal. First, we unwind the tags array, group it by the individual tags and increment the score for each occurrence of the respective tag. Next, we [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#upsert-option) `lastRun` in the `tagStats` collection, which we can do since MongoDB is schemaless. Next, we create a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/), which only holds values for documents in which the indexed field exists. In case the index already exists, `ensureIndex` is an extremely cheap query; however, since we are going to use that query in our code, we don't need to create the index manually. With this procedure, the following query

```js
db.tagStats.find(
 {lastRun:{ $lte: new Date( ISODate().getTime() - 300000 ) } },
 {_id:0, lastRun:1}
)
```

becomes a [covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query): A query which is answered from the index, which tends to reside in RAM, making this query lightning fast (slightly less than 0.5 msecs median in my tests). So what does this query do? It will return a record when the last run of the aggregation was run more than 5 minutes ( 5*60*1000 = 300000 msecs) ago. Of course, you can adjust this to your needs.

Now, we can wrap it up:

```js
var hasToRun = db.tagStats.find(
  {lastRun:{ $lte: new Date( ISODate().getTime() - 300000 ) } },
  {_id:0, lastRun:1}
);

if(hasToRun){

  db.tags.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$tags"},
    {$group: {_id:"$tags", score:{"$sum":1} } },
    {$out:"tagStats"}
  )

  db.tagStats.update(
    {'lastRun':{$exists:true}},
    {'lastRun':new Date()},
    {upsert:true}
  );

  db.tagStats.ensureIndex({lastRun:1},{sparse:true});

}
// For all stats
var tagsStats = db.tagStats.find({score:{$exists:true}});
// score for a specific tag
var scoreForTag = db.tagStats.find({score:{$exists:true},_id:"tag1"});
```

#### Alternative approach

If real time results ***really*** matter and you need the stats for all the tags, simply use the aggregation without saving it to another collection:

```js
db.tags.aggregate(
  {$unwind:"$tags"},
  {$group: { _id:"$tags", score:{"$sum":1} } },
)
```

If you only need the results for one specific tag at a time, a real time approach could be to use a special index, create a covered query and simply count the results:

```js
db.tags.ensureIndex({tags:1})
var numberOfOccurences = db.tags.find({tags:"tag1"},{_id:0,tags:1}).count();
```

Comment: Thanks I accepted this answer as it covers well an alternative approach - however: the aggregate query you are doing on `db.tags` - which does not exist in my scenario. The scenario is that all `tags` arrays are nested in parent documents. So I somehow would have to unwind all the parent documents, sub-unwind the tags, group them, and so on. Could you hint on that? thanks!

Comment: `db.tags` is just an arbitrary name for the collection... Try it as written, with your actual collection names. ;)

Comment: I know that `db.tags` is an arbitrary collection name - it contains the tags. But that is not my scenario. As I wrote: "The scenario is that all tags arrays are nested in parent documents." So what I have, said with your naming, is `db.docs.tags`. So I have the tags split between different documents - as also shown in my initial post above.

Answer (score 0):

answering your questions:

- B): you don't have to calculate the dif yourself  [use $addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
- A): you can get the counts via aggregation framework with a combination of [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and $count

Comment: Thanks first of all! However: I am aware of the aggregation framework but is it faster / better for this purpose? Is the separate collection approach I chose not faster?
Also: thanks for the hint to "addToSet" but I don't think it would be enough: it only appends, but I will also need to remove deleted tags. Plus if I stick to the separate collection approach then I need to know which tags were appended.

Comment: No it will not be faster :(,  it will only relieve you from the trouble of keeping counts by yourself, still can be acceptable solution depending on collection size and how often you do those inserts.

Comment: You are right, my approach has a critical drawback: I do a lot of extra work on every tag insert / update. But I am probably faster on every query for tag counts which is the far more common operation - but this is basically one of my questions: is my approach really faster when wanting to know the counts? Or is the aggregation framework version equally fast if one defines the right indexes? How / what to define as indexes?

Comment: Sure it is faster when you want to know the counts, whatever you do with indexes it will never be faster comparing to a plain query on collection2